# Is there a maximum number of named ranges in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, pygsheets

I am writing a Python program to extract values from a google sheet and I am running into a weird problem whereby named ranges that I know I have put in to the sheet starts disappearing. When I re-enter them, some other range disappears. This has happened after I have added a large number of named ranges. I don't get any error message and it is seems somewhat random which ranges disappears. Could it be that there is a maximum number of named ranges and that some old ranges are removed automatically when I add a new one? I have search for any maximum number in the documentation but haven't been able to find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Currently nine hundred and ninety nine (999).

['Suck it and see'](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/56771/60716) courtesy [Jacob Jan Tuinstra](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/29140/jacob-jan-tuinstra).

Comment: Thanks! We can the document regarding that be found?